# Get % used of zram in script

Tags: debian, scripting, raspberry-pi, raspbian, zram

I've got a script that collects various bits of system data and reports this via MQTT to a central local server. I recently implemented zram with priority over swap to see if this offers a performance boost. As part of monitoring this I need to be able to workout the % used zram, so that it can be reported.

I know that I can see basic stats for swap & zram with the following commands:

`cat /proc/swap` or `swapon -s`

```
Filename        Type            Size     Used      Priority
/var/swap       file            102396   0         -2
/dev/zram0      partition       5055516  170752    5
```

or

`zramctl`

```
NAME        ALGORITHM DISKSIZE  DATA    COMPR  TOTAL  STREAMS MOUNTPOINT
/dev/zram0  lz4       4.8G      165.5M  58.4M  62.8M  4       [SWAP]
```

But these don't present a % used and in the case of the first 2 commands also report the standard swap. Is there a way to determine & output the % used zram and nothing else in a single-line command?

edit:
It looks like `swapon -s` offers the easiest results to use since it gives size and used values in the zram line. If anyone can offer a way to return just the %used I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us the output of these commands on your system. If you know the total amount of zram and the amount currently used, converting to a percentage is trivial. But we can't help you parse data you don't show us.

Comment: @terdon Ok, I've included the output.

Comment: `bc<<<"scale=2;($used / $total) * 100"`

Comment: `zswap` has some debug values available: `sudo grep -R . /sys/kernel/debug/zswap/` Maybe `zram` has something similar.

Comment: @terdon Is that enough to go on?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this easily from your `swapon -s` output:

```
$ swapon -s | awk '$1~/\/zram/{printf "%.2f%%\n", ($4/$3)*100}' 
3.38%
```